# roll() and add()

Tags: java, calendar

what is the diference between roll() and add() in java ?

/*this the class that i wanted to see if i can use add in place of roll . and thank you */

```
    mydate.roll(Calendar.MINUTE, true);
    int nextminutes = mydate.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int nexttseconds = mydate.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    while(count<1000000){
        System.out.println(sentence);
        GregorianCalendar now = new GregorianCalendar();

    if(mydate.get(Calendar.MINUTE)>= nextminutes){
        break;
    }   
    }
    count++;
    System.out.println("i wrote the sentence"+count+"time.");


}
```

}

Comment: It depends how you've implemented them... unless your asking about a specific API i.e. Calendar?

Comment: Please elaborate, and tell us which class you're trying to work with.  There is no 'roll()' or 'add()' method in Java, though many classes do have an 'add()' method, and some probably have a 'roll()' method too.

Comment: Roll doesn't affect larger time fields. For example if you start with 12/31/99 and you roll(Calendar.MONTH, 8) you'll get 8/31/99 where add would have incremented the year to 00. Topic was closed, but my answer is probably what he's looking for.

Comment: Currently the question is closed. I think calendar as tag makes it clear enough that it is about the Calendar interface, sure he should have mentioned this also in the question. Consider he is new here.

Answer (score 9):

If you're working on a [calendar](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=289596):

"**Calendar.roll** changes a specific unit and leaves 'larger' ( in terms of time - month is 'larger' than day) units unchanged. The API example is that given a date of August 31, 1999, rolling by (Calendar.MONTH, 8) yields April 30, 1999. That is, the DAY was changed to meet April's maximum, but the 'larger' unit, YEAR, was unchanged.

**Calendar.add** will cause the next 'larger' unit to change, if necessary. That is, given a date of August 31, 1999, add(Calendar.MONTH, 8) yields April 30, 2000. add() also forces a recalculation of milliseconds and all fields.
"